# SQL Change time values with delayed minutes to "previous" minute

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's an example:
My database has several entries where the time values are:

```
10:00:00
10:10:00
10:20:00
...
```

Then sometimes there are these values where we have a 1 minute delay like:

```
10:20:00
10:31:00 <-
10:40:00
10:51:00 <-
```

And I wanted these numbers to, each, go to their respective minutes:

```
10:20:00
10:31:00 -> 10:30:00
10:40:00
10:51:00 -> 10:50:00
```

Edit: The time are sole entries, I have my date value in another column, for visualization my columns are

```
keyDate     keyTime   Sequency   Value
12-03-2018  10:40:00  12         143
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide the type of value you are working with.  If these are "timestamp" values, then I would expect a date component.  Also, are there *other* values in the column as well?

Comment: `10:00:00` is not a timestamp value (at least not in "SQL"), it's a `time`. A "timestamp" typically includes a date as well

Comment: My bad, fixed it, thought timestamp was only times. But yes it's only times.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 SELECT  
    CONVERT(TIME,CASE WHEN RIGHT(datepart(minute,BeginTime),1) = 1 
        THEN 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),datepart(Hour,BeginTime)) +':'
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),datepart(minute,BeginTime) - 1) 
            +':'
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),datepart(second,BeginTime)) 
        ELSE 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),BeginTime)  
        END)
FROM @tbl
```

For example

```
Declare @tbl Table(
ArrangeId INT ,
BeginTime   TIME,
EndDate   NVARCHAR(50),
DeptId INT
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'7:20:00','22:30',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(3,'7:10:00','23:00',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(2,'7:11:00','23:59',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(4,'6:10:00','22:30',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(4,'5:11:00','22:30',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(4,'5:31:00','22:30',NULL)


SELECT  
    CONVERT(TIME,CASE WHEN RIGHT(datepart(minute,BeginTime),1) = 1 
        THEN 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),datepart(Hour,BeginTime)) +':'
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),datepart(minute,BeginTime) - 1) 
            +':'
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),datepart(second,BeginTime)) 
        ELSE 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),BeginTime)  
        END)
FROM @tbl
```

Comment: Tried by replacing BeginTime with keyTime, but I get an SQL syntax error at CASE.

Comment: You have also used  BeginTime   field datatype is varchar(8)